# Is it possible to specify condition in Month()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to show only the rows that have for example Months = '1'

```
select IssueAmount, MONTH( CONVERT(date, IssueDate )) as Months
from LoanAccount
```

If I add a **where** condition, I get the following error message:

****'Msg 207, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 4
Nom de colonne non valide : 'Months'.'****

This is the code I was using:

```
select IssueAmount, MONTH( CONVERT(date, IssueDate )) as Months
from LoanAccount where Months = '1'
```

Comment: Are you looking at only one year or could IssueDate be across many years?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `alias` name in `same` select statement `where` clause because `where` clause is `evaluated` before the `select` so alias name won't be available in `where` clause. So directly use the `month` function in `where` clause

```
select IssueAmount,  Month(CONVERT(date, IssueDate ))
from LoanAccount where Month(CONVERT(date, IssueDate )) = 1
```

or make the query as `sub-select` and use the `alias` name to filter the records in `outer query`

```
select * from 
(
select IssueAmount, datepart(CONVERT(date, IssueDate ), IssueDate )  as Months
from LoanAccount
) a
where Months =1
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not allowed to use alias of result column in WHERE clause

try this:

```
select 
    IssueAmount, 
    MONTH(CONVERT(date, IssueDate)) as Months
from LoanAccount 
where MONTH(CONVERT(date, IssueDate)) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use SQL [datepart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174420.aspx)

e.g

```
select datepart(month,getdate())
```

Your Query should be like this.

```
select IssueAmount, datepart(month, IssueDate ) as Months
from LoanAccount where datepart(month, IssueDate )= 1
```

Comment: @NoDisplayName why not??

Comment: @husskar folllow the link and you'll figure it yourself. :)

Comment: i read it and thank you
but i didn't notice that because thats not the main solution but sql datepart()   was .
btw thank you . @NoDisplayName